# IDE drive shows up in dmesg etc., but is not accessible

Tags: data-recovery, ide

I found an old IDE drive (Seagate ST36422A) of mine, and I'm hoping to find some nostalgic data on it.

So far, my system seems to recognize the drive, but the assigned `/dev/sdh` file doesn't show up in `lsblk` or `fdisk -l`. I'm also unable to use `dd`.

I'm connecting through a generic *usb2ide/sata* converter that uses an external power coord. The drive is set to slave-mode.

---

Output of `dmesg`:

```
[ 1672.540299] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 1672.562867] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0611
[ 1672.562871] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
[ 1672.562873] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 20171228
[ 1672.563895] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1672.564010] scsi host7: usb-storage 4-2:1.0 
[ 1673.569044] scsi host7: scsi scan: INQUIRY result too short (5), using 36
[ 1673.569051] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  ATA/ATAPI Device      PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1673.569467] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 0
[ 1673.570291] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

New `lsusb` entry:

```
Bus 004 Device 007: ID 1f75:0611 Innostor Technology Corporation
```

New `/dev/` file:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr  4 16:43 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic_ATA_ATAPI_Device_20171228-0:0 -> ../../sdh
```

Comment: @Christopher The Converter came with a 4-pole connector for power. I'll try the master mode once I find a jumper. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm having this same issue, did you ever figure this out? It doesn't seem to be a problem with power on my end, as I can physically feel the platter spinning.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a `/dev/sdh` device and no partitions (`/dev/sdh1`, `/dev/sdh2`, etc.), that means that Linux sees the drive but believes that it is missing a partition table. The drive's data may be corrupted: I have no idea how much of the drive is readable. Could it be due to incorrect master/slave settings or the USB interface? Possibly, but if it were those issues, I would expect that you wouldn't see any detected device at all.

As this isn't a huge disk, I would recommend making a backup of the whole drive so you can use a program like [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover using the copy. Working on a backup both is faster (you can use your faster internal drive) and safer (you're not messing with the original data.) The ST-36422A appears to be a [6.4GB drive](ftp://ftp.seagate.com/techsuppt/at/st36422a.txt), so `dd if=/dev/sdh of=/path/to/recoverfile bs=1M count=6103 status=progress` or (if you have [ddrescue](https://www.data-medics.com/forum/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-with-bad-sectors-using-ddrescue-t133.html)) `ddrescue -A -J -d /dev/sdh /path/to/recoverfile /path/to/mapfile`.